# How to print an octal value's corresponding UTF-8 character in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, utf-8, character-set

I expected `printf %s '\<octal_character_value>'` to do the trick, but it doesn't:

```
printf %s '\101'
```

Outputs:

```
\101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you want `%b`. From `help printf`:

```
In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1),
printf interprets:

  %b    expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
```

And:

```
$ printf "%b\n" '\101'
A
```

I don't know if it works for Unicode characters in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "\107"}'
G
```

Or the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```
$ velour -n 'print n_chr(+n_baseconv(107, 8, 10))'
G
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with unicode as long as you type out the byte.

```
$ gprintf '\353\200\200' | odview

0000000           8421611                                                
          ""  **  **                                                    
          353 200 200                                                    
           ?  80  80                                                    
          235 128 128                                                    
           eb  80  80                                                    
                  8421611                                                

0000003
```

The `%b` operator isn't necessary (as long as your octals aren't `\0NNN` form, at least in the macOS 11.5 bash3 built-in, the macOS BSD-UNIX `printf`, and also `gnu-printf 8.32`.

This character is `U+B000` (n=45,056). The decomposed one is more verbose but works the same

```
gprintf '\341\204\201\341\205\260\341\206\267' | odview

0000000        3783361761      2262937733             183                
          ᄁ  **  **   ᅰ  **  **   ᆷ  **  **                            
          341 204 201 341 205 260 341 206 267                            
           ?  84  81   ?  85   ?   ?  86   ?                            
          225 132 129 225 133 176 225 134 183                            
           e1  84  81  e1  85  b0  e1  86  b7                            
               -511605535     -2032029563             183
```